# how modify session in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session-variables, session-cookies

I am using Rails 3.  I was coding a controller very verbose. So i am trying refactoring the controller.

I coded a class called ProductMaker which make a product and modify session (product task for wizard form as current_step, if the request is a refresh, etc)

This class has method that receiving session as parameter, modify and then return this new session.

Controller action:

```
  def new
    #INITIALIZE CODE
    session[:refresh] ||= SortedArray.new [1]
    #...MORE CODE
  end

    def create
     #...MUCH CODE
     unless Utilities.is_refresh(session[:refresh])
        #...more code
        session = ProductMaker.some_method_which_return_session(session) #KEY PROBLEM LINE
        #...more code
     end
     #... MORE CODE
    end
```

My ProductMaker class in lib folder:

```
class ProductMaker

def self.some_method_which_return_session(session)
 session[:any_key] = "some value"
 return session
end

end
```

However when I write the KEY PROBLEM LINE the session is a nil value. If i comment this line the session is a ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash.

Which could be the problem?
How could i refactoring controller logic, that modify many session keys and 'fill' a model depending the session values, to model/class ?

UPDATE:

I am reading about binding in ruby.

How could modify the session using bindings and eval method?

If you have other ideas, please post your answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I use bindings.

For example:

```
class SessionManager

self.update(session, binding)
 eval "#{session} = 0", binding
end

end

class SomeController < ApplicationController

def foo_action_1
  session[:refresh] = 1
end

def example_ajax_modify_session
   a = session[:refresh] == 1 #true
   SessionManager.update("session[:refresh]", binding)
   b = session[:refresh] == 1 #false
   a == b #false because a == 1 and b == 0
end
```

I had to modify and manage many session values so before I has a very verbose controller.
Now I could refactoring this logic to model.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `session =` on the "key problem line". This creates a local variable for the `create` method which shadows the `session` method on `ActionController::Base`. The local variable is `nil` before you assign it (not non-existent!) so the end result is that `session == nil` for the whole method, which obviously breaks everything. So: don't assign `session`. Call your return value something else.

Comment: thank you very much. If I understood the problem yesterday. My new problem was to modify the session variable. finally I use binding.

Answer (score 0):

I use binding technique. So i pass the context (simulating parameter pass reference variables).

Example

class OwnController < ApplicationController
   def my_action
     SettingManager.modify("session[:session]", binding)
   end
end

class SettingManager
  def self.modify(session, binding)
    eval "#{session}.any_value = 5" binding
    eval "#{session}.other_value = 'value'", binding
  end
end